# Is there a way trigger a signal from another signal in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

In my application, I am introducing a new signal, which has to be emitted when another signal is emitted. Is this possible in Qt?

Writing a slot just to emit this signal feels so primitive and lame.

I have to connect the button `signalClicked()` to my own signal, say `sendSignal(enumtype)`, and send data with the second signal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect signal to signal with new syntax QT5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150034/how-to-connect-signal-to-signal-with-new-syntax-qt5)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without creating additional slot. Just connect signal to signal:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(someSignal()),this,SIGNAL(anotherSignal()));
```

[More information in doc.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect)

You can share data in connection as usual. Dirty example:

```
QWidget* obj = new QWidget;
obj->setWindowTitle("WindowTitle");
//share data, pass wrong data to the signal
QObject::connect(obj,SIGNAL(objectNameChanged(QString)),obj,SIGNAL(windowTitleChanged(QString)));
QObject::connect(obj,&QWidget::windowTitleChanged,[](QString str) {qDebug() << str;});
obj->setObjectName("ObjectName");
qDebug() << "But window title is"<< obj->windowTitle();
obj->show();
```

Output is:

```
"ObjectName" 
But window title is "WindowTitle"
```

But there is no way to do something like:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(someSignal()),this,SIGNAL(anotherSignal("with custom data")));
```

In this case, you need a separate slot.