# How to connect signal to signal with Qt5's new syntax?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I am trying to connect a signal to a signal using the new syntax:

```
connect(ui->line,&QLineEdit::returnPressed,ui->button,&QPushButton::clicked);
```

But the compiler throws an error, with all this the old syntax works:

```
connect(ui->line,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),ui->button,SIGNAL(clicked()));
```

I know this can be connected to function click:

```
connect(ui->line,&QLineEdit::returnPressed,ui->button,&QPushButton::click);
```

But is there a way to connect it to the signal use new syntax?

Comment: Show us the error you get. Is it because `clicked` takes a `bool` argument that is not present in the `returnPressed` signal?

Comment: @Botje static assertion failed: The slot requires more arguments than the signal provides. -- static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible. -- but why then does the old syntax work?

Answer (score 6):

From a quick glance at the documentation, the mismatch stems from the extra argument to the `clicked`signal.

One option is to use a lambda to inject that argument:

```
connect(ui->line,&QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, [this]() { ui->button->clicked(false); });
```

Comment: Only one thing. From the question it seems that @Artem072 wants to emit ```clicked(true)``` once ```returnPressed``` is triggered. Am I right?

Comment: @Botje ui cannot be caputred as it is a member variable, you need to capture this to be able to access it in your lambda. Furthermore you call  `ui->clicked(false);` instead of the button method: `ui->button->clicked(false);`

Comment: I myself made a mistake by assuming that we do not need to pass the target argument. I put it back (reason [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments))

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a lambda for this. But your example shows the confusion with the old syntax well. What would it do? Would it emit the signal with true or false?

I am sure it is documented somewhere, if nowhere else, then in the code. But surely, with the new syntax, being explicit, makes the code more readable, right?

So, I would write something like this if I were you:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QPushButton pushButton;
    QObject::connect(&lineEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [&pushButton]() {emit pushButton.clicked(true);});
    return app.exec();
}
```

And for those, who just want to know whether or not the receiver can be a signal with the new connect syntax, the answer is that the receiver can be a signal, not just slot. This is why I also prefer to call this "new connect syntax" rather than "new signal/slot syntax". So, a simple signal to signal "mapping" would be this:

```
connect(
    sender, &Sender::valueChanged,
    receiver, &Receiver::valueChanged,
);
```