# Use Qt Signal and Slots when object is not defined in main class

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qt5

My code has following structure:

- include

  -> myserver.h

  -> mythread.h

  -> mainwindow.h
- src

  -> myserver.cpp

  -> mythread.cpp

  -> mainwindow.cpp
- main.cpp

MyServer class creates a new thread for each connection. In that thread, I am reading the data from the client and want to send it to mainwindow.cpp. For this, I am thinking of using signal and slots. Since I have not declared MyThread in mainwindow, I am not able to use connect().

mythread.h:

```
signals:
    void newDataRecieved(QVector<double> x,QVector<double> y);
```

mythread.cpp:

```
void MyThread::func(){
   .
   .
   .
   emit newDataRecieved(x,yC);
}
```

myserver.cpp:

```cpp
void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    // We have a new connection
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

    // connect signal/slot
    // once a thread is not needed, it will be beleted later
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    
    thread->start();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
public slots:
    void newValues(QVector<double> x,QVector<double> y);
```

main.cpp:

```
.
.
#include "myserver.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    .
    .
    w.show();
    MyServer server;
    server.startServer();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: please  provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a signal

```
void newDataRecieved(QVector<double> x,QVector<double> y);
```

In MyServer class and then connect the signal newDataRecieved form MyThread to the same signal of MyServer. Then in mainwindow connect a slot to the signal form MyServer.

[Is there a way trigger a signal from another signal in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993043/is-there-a-way-trigger-a-signal-from-another-signal-in-qt)

**[EDIT]**

Something like this:

myserver.h:

```
signals:
    void newDataRecieved(QVector<double> x,QVector<double> y);
```

myserver.cpp:

```
void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
    {
    // We have a new connection
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

    // connect signal/slot
    // once a thread is not needed, it will be beleted later
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(newDataRecieved(QVector<double>, QVector<double>)), this, SIGNAL(newDataRecieved(QVector<double>, QVector<double>)));

    thread->start();
```

}

Comment: I had just one doubt in this approach how should I send the data from MyServer class to mainwindow? As the server class is initiated in main.cpp

Comment: You can do it in two ways: the first is simply do the connection in the main.cpp

    w.show();
    MyServer server;
    QObject::connect(&server, SIGNAL(...), &w, SLOT(...));

The second is to passs a pointer to the mainwindow to MyServer constructor and then do the connection inside the constructor, but is ugly


    MyServer server(&w);


Remember to #include<QObject>

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I finally tested this out and is working fine. Another method of doing it was that I created a new thread in that I was calling server class. But using connect in main.cpp seems to be a better approach.